# Does ISerializable interface work with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Does ISerializable interface work with Entity Framework?

Basically, my issue is I have a couple of XML columns in my database that I want to parse on the front end but I'd rather not write out a parsing property and instead do it in the ISerializable methods.  Does EF support ISerializable or is there another interface I can use?

Comment: are you using Code First ?

Comment: Yes, for now, though I'm trying not to.  The fields are stored in the DB as string.

Comment: It is more common to use `DataContractSerializer` with EF...

Comment: A better approach would be to load the data as a string to an Entity, then deserialize the string when mapping to your domain layer.  This assumes, of course, that you have two different layers.

Comment: @MarcGravell, DataContractSerializer would work but it seems like overkill.  So far I have only two properties in my domain that require the XML parsing.  I was hoping to use an interface that EF would automatically use if present (if such a thing exists).

Comment: Not to mention, anything remotely related to WCF is steeply unelegant.

Comment: @ThinkingSites well, `ISerializable` is largely obsolete, and I always advise people **not** to use it - it has a lot of issues associated with it (mainly versioning). But: my advice here would be: create a separate DTO model (in particular, this isolates your persistence from changes to the schema, and things like lazy-loading etc - which can really plan havoc with serializers)